# Expectation value of $p^2 (1/r) + (1/r) p^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation

I'm trying to derive $\langle kl | \lbrace 1/r , p^2 \rbrace | nl \rangle$, where the states satisfy the equation of motion (I omit factors of $1/2m$ etc.):

$$(p^2 + V)| n,l \rangle = E_n | n,l \rangle$$

and $\lbrace A,B \rbrace = AB + BA$ is the anticommutator.
I have two solutions at hand that differ. In general I can write:

$$\langle k,l | \lbrace 1/r , p^2 \rbrace | n,l \rangle = \langle k,l | 1/r~p^2 + p^2~1/r | n,l \rangle$$

and I can use that $p^2 \propto -\nabla^2$ and $\nabla^2 1/r \propto -\delta^{(3)}(r)$.

Now I want to let $p^2$ act first on the respective states and let $1/r$ act later on, such that I can use the e.o.m. Thus I have:

$$\langle k,l | 1/r~p^2 + p^2~1/r | n,l \rangle = \langle k,l | 1/r~(E_n - V) + (E_k - V)~1/r | n,l \rangle$$

In this solution I let the first summand act on the ket and I let the second summand act on the bra. However, when I do it the other way around, using the product rule $\nabla^2 (1/r~\psi) = (\nabla^2 1/r) \psi + 1/r (\nabla^2 \psi)$ and use the e.o.m for the second term I obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle k,l | 1/r~p^2 + p^2~1/r | n,l \rangle &=& \langle k,l | \delta^{(3)}(r) + (E_k - V) + (E_n - V) + \delta^{(3)}(r) | n,l \rangle\\ &=& \langle k,l | 1/r~(E_n - V) + (E_k - V)~1/r | nl \rangle + 2 \langle kl | \delta^{(3)}(r) | n,l \rangle
\end{eqnarray}

These two solutions are clearly different if and only if both of the wave functions do not vanish at the origin. This is to say that these two solutions give different results for s-waves.

Am I missing something essential here? Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: I obviously missed that $\nabla^2 (1/r~\psi) = (\nabla^2 1/r)\psi + 1/r(\nabla^2\psi) + 2 \langle \vec{\nabla} 1/r , \vec{\nabla}\psi \rangle$ which applied to the above problem introduces even more confusion, since it gives the additional term $2 \langle \vec{\nabla} 1/r , \vec{\nabla}p^2 \rangle$ which I (i) do not know how to evaluate and (ii) does not obviously cancel the $\delta$ contribution...

Comment: Yes, the Hamiltonian is spherically symmetric but it is not the Hydrogen Hamiltonian. The potential has the form $V = - \frac{C_F \alpha_s}{r} \cdot (1 + \sum_{k} a_k(r) (\frac{\alpha_s}{4\pi})^{k})$, where the $a_k$ are functions of $r$ and of QCD constants (logs of $r$ and coefficients of the QCD $\beta$-function). Therefore the radial part of the wave function is not Hydrogen like but the angular part is still given by the Spherical harmonics, which is the reason why I keep the $l$ dependence.

Answer (score 2):

A paradigm is worth a hundred puffs of bloviation.

Exploit your spherical symmetry, $\hat{r}\cdot \vec{\nabla}=\partial_r$, and $\vec{\nabla} f(r) =\hat{r} \partial_r f(r)$; and, since the challenge you are concerned with is the singularity at the origin, *r* =0, we might as well drop all *l*>0, which are softer than *s*-waves, as you noted.

In your $\hbar=1$, $m=2$ units, consider, for simplicity, the *s*-waves of the Hydrogen hamiltonian, sufficient to illustrate the point,
$$
H=p^2-2/r= -\frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r (r^2\partial_r) -\frac{2}{r}~.\tag1
$$
The Hilbert space integrations will be over $4\pi \int^\infty_0 dr~ r^2 ~~$ .
Thus,
$$
\nabla^2 \frac{1}{r}=-4\pi \delta^{(3)} (\vec{r})~,\tag2
$$
which, in our radial context, amounts to just 
$$
-p^2 \frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{r^2} \partial \left(r^2\partial \frac{1}{r}\right )=- \frac{\delta(r)}{r^2}~.\tag{2'}
$$

The ground eigenstate (*n* =1) is then
$$
\psi_0= \frac{e^{-r}}{\sqrt{\pi/2}}   \qquad \Longrightarrow  E_0=-1, \tag3
$$
while the first excited state (*n* =2) is 
$$
\psi_1=  \frac{e^{-r/2}}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}  (2-r)   \qquad \Longrightarrow  E_1=-1/4, \tag4
$$
so that $\langle \psi_1| \psi_0\rangle=0$, since $\int_0^\infty \! dx~ e^{-x} x^n =n! ~~$ .

---

It follows that 
$$
\frac{1}{r}~ p^2 ~\psi_0= \left (\frac{2}{r^2}-\frac{1}{r}\right )\psi_0 \tag5 \\
 p^2 \left (\frac{1}{r} \psi_0 \right) = \left(\frac{\delta(r)}{r^2}-\frac{1}{r}\right )\psi_0 . 
$$
(The second eqn is the [screened Poisson eqn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation) -- "massive photon".) Hence 
$$
[p^2,1/r]\psi_0 = \left ( \frac{\delta(r)}{r^2}-\frac{2}{r^2}  \right) \psi_0. \tag{5'}
$$

(In general, $[p^2,1/r]=\frac{\delta(r)}{r^2} + \frac{2}{r^2} \partial_r ~$ .)

Now note that 
$$
\langle \psi_0|[p^2,1/r]| \psi_0\rangle=0= \langle \psi_1|[p^2,1/r]| \psi_1\rangle .\tag6
$$

Consequently, as per your first evaluation path using hermiticity, 
$$
\langle \psi_0|\{p^2,1/r\}| \psi_0\rangle=
\langle \psi_0|(H+2/r)  \frac{1}{r} +  \frac{1}{r} (H+2/r)  | \psi_0\rangle=
\langle \psi_0| \frac{2}{r} \left(\frac{2}{r}-1\right) | \psi_0\rangle=12.\tag7
$$
Acting on just the right ket, as per your latter intention, also yields the same, 
$$
\langle \psi_0|\left( \frac{\delta(r)}{r^2} -\frac{2}{r} +\frac{2}{r^2} \right ) | \psi_0\rangle=12.\tag{7'}
$$
You never had to cancel the *δ* : it does not fail to know its place. It had better be, since the expectation of the commutator vanishes.

But this helpful vanishing is not actually necessary for consistency. More generally, as per your off-diagonal example, 
$$
\langle \psi_1|\{p^2,1/r\}| \psi_0\rangle=  \langle \psi_1|\left(-\frac{1}{4}+ \frac{2}{r}\right)\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{r}\left(-1+\frac{2}{r}\right ) | \psi_0\rangle=86/27~. \tag8
$$
Alternatively, simply acting on the right, as done above, 
$$
\langle \psi_1|\left( \frac{\delta(r)}{r^2} -\frac{2}{r} +\frac{2}{r^2} \right) | \psi_0\rangle=\int dr e^{-3r/2}( \delta(r) -2r +2  )(2-r)  =86/27~.\tag{8'}
$$

Your two approaches are consistent, after all. The linchpin is that the  integration by parts implicit in the hermitean maneuver works free of surface terms at the origin.

This is not hard to generalize. For singular potentials (unlike yours, I understand), i.e. with $r^2V(r)$ not vanishing at the origin, take a look at 
[Khelasvili & Nadareishvili 2010](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.3546099).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I actually just realized that my first approach was not right, since a operator acting on a bra actually acts as its hermitian conjugate, i.e. $O| nl \rangle \to \langle nl | O^{\dagger}$. In this case $O = p^{2} 1/r$ and thus $O^{\dagger} = 1/r p^{2}$, because $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger} A^{\dagger}$.
This sort of solves the first mystery, telling me that I will always get the $\delta$-contribution - which of course vanishes for non s-waves...

Comment: Yet, I'm still confused with the scalar product part $2 \langle \vec{\nabla} 1/r , \vec{\nabla} p^{2} \rangle$. Because I can not see at the moment how this should be evaluated.

Comment: ??? What you wrote right here is meaningless. The gradient acts on the wavefunction. It came from $p^2$. I evaluated them both implicitly for you.   In detail, $\nabla(1/r)\cdot\nabla \psi = -\partial_r \psi /r^2$, which you integrate with the bra \psi and be mindful of the radial measure in the r-integral. I do it above, don't I???

Comment: But it is still alarming that you feel you have to use $\nabla$s and not $\hat{r}\cdot \nabla$s. For radially symmetric problems you instantly go to  the radial, one variable expressions and the proper radial measures and expressions--the angles are fictitious.

Comment: This pestiferous cross term seems to be a recurrent point of confusion... It reared its ugly head in [317037](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317037/is-this-problem-from-griffiths-classical-electromagnetism-correct?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well. Try a toy problem to convince yourself that if you are explicitly integrating by parts, you are doing something off, or inefficiently.