# Is this problem from Griffiths' "Classical electromagnetism" correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, calculus, greens-functions

I am talking about pbl 2.46 pag 107.

The potential $$\frac{A}{r} \, \exp{(-\lambda r)}$$ is given I have to find the charge density and the electric field.

The book says the solution for the charge density is: $$\left[\delta^3(r)-\dfrac{\lambda^2}{r} \, \exp{(-\lambda r)}\right]\, \epsilon_0\, A$$

The first part comes from $\nabla^2 \, \dfrac{1}{r}$ , the second comes from $\nabla^2\,\exp{(-\lambda r)}$.

I think this part is missing: $2\,\nabla\, \dfrac{1}{r} \, \cdot\, \nabla\,\exp{(-\lambda r)} $.

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Related to [315882](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315882/). Indeed, your intermediate distance proposed term is $2\lambda \exp(-\lambda r)/r^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is but the [screened Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation). Since the functions are radial, only the radial part of the Laplacian survives, 
$$
\nabla^2 (e^{-\lambda r}/r) = \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r ( r^2 \partial_r (e^{-\lambda r}/r))= \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r \left ( -\lambda r e^{-\lambda r} +e^{-\lambda r} r^2\partial_r \frac{1}{r}\right )\\
= \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r \left(  r^2\partial_r \frac{1}{r}\right ) ~ e^{-\lambda r} -\lambda  e^{-\lambda r} \left(\frac{1}{r^2}+\partial_r \frac{1}{r} \right  ) + \lambda^2 \frac{ e^{-\lambda r}}{r}.
$$
Note the cross $O(\lambda)$ term vanishes.

Since
$$
\nabla^2 \frac{1}{r}=-4\pi \delta^{(3)} (\vec{r})= -\frac{\delta(r)}{r^2},
$$
one has 
$$
(\nabla^2 -\lambda^2) \left (\frac{e^{-\lambda r}}{r}\right)=-\frac{\delta(r)}{r^2}.
$$

So your text is just fine. You probably misunderstand, that, in fact, $\nabla^2 e^{-\lambda r}= (\lambda^2  -2\lambda/r )e^{-\lambda r}$, as  evident from above. This additional $O(\lambda)$ term here exactly cancels the cross term you wrote down. (Try evaluating $\nabla^2 r$ to see the point.)